# how to concatinate in Webhook

Tags: webhooks

I am very new with [webhook.com](http://www.webhook.com) , But i have setup the cms and able to manage my site the issue is **i want to join two strings** with the if else condition

```
 {% if link!="" %} 
       {% set link = object.menu_url %}  menu link will look like "https://www.example.com" it is ok
    {% else %} 
       {% set link = object.menu_id %}  menu link will look like "#menulid"
    {% endif %}
```

i just want to add # with the menu id something like **{% set link = "#".object.menu_id %}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use + sign to concatinate like

```
{% set link = "#"+object.menu_id %}
```